Converting japanese fullwidth characters typed by user to halfwidth character in the same input field
There's an input field, when the user will type any fullwidth Japanese character (numbers only) it won't be displayed on that input field. It'll be converted to its respective halfwidth character and, then that halfwidth character will be visible inside that same input field.
If user type ０, this ０ will not be shown in the input field, it'll show the converted halfwidth 0. In my case the problem is if the user types ０, the function is running twice and showing 00, but it should be only 0. Can anybody please help me to sort it out?
<input type="text" id="inputField" oninput="convertToHalfWidth(this.value)">
<script>
    function convertToHalfWidth(input) {
        console.log(input);
        // Map of full-width to half-width numbers
        const fullToHalfMap = {
            '０': '0', '１': '1', '２': '2', '３': '3', '４': '4', '５': '5', '６': '6', '７': '7', '８': '8', '９': '9'
        };

        // Replacing full-width numbers with their half-width counterparts
        const convertedInput = input.replace(/[０-９]/g, match => fullToHalfMap[match]);

        // Updating the input field with the converted value
        document.getElementById('inputField').value = convertedInput;
    }
</script> 


I can't seem to repro this issue. Can you see if you can repro this in a playground environment with just this code? Additionally, can you get a repro which just uses ASCII (i.e. converting all 'a' characters to 'A')? Using plain ASCII will help narrow down problems since most contributors will have to copy/paste these fullwidth characters.

I agree with DyllonGagnier, perhaps adding a workable snippit in your question that reproduces your issue would get you a quicker response to your issue.

Can't repro either with macOS Full-width Romaji IME on both Chrome and Firefox. Are you sure there isn't another script that tries to handle input events on that element?

@kaiido The problem will only reproduce by typing in any characters that uses text composition system and uses full-width number as default candidate. I've tried multiple Japanese Full-width IME but all of them uses half-width numbers as the default candidate. Can repro in Chinese IME though.

As per spec:

The start of a composition is marked by dispatching a compositionstart event. During a composition session, whenever a text composition system updates its active text passage, a compositionupdate event is dispatched. After each compositionupdate event, a pair of beforeinput and input events are dispatched.

The problem is an input event with type insertCompositionText is fired whenever an a composition session is updated. Even for simple full width characters like numbers and space that doesn't require multiple symbols composed using an IME window, there will still be two input event fired by compositionupdate. (Reproduced on Chinese IME and Japanese full-width Katakana IME.)
Note that this problem won't be reproduced by pasting the full characters because there won't be any composition session started. Only an input event with type insertText will be started.
One solution is to use an additional compositionend event to handle composition input types. (Or a simple onkeyup is enough if you are okay with the delay between keydown and keyup.)


const inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');
const fullToHalfMap = {
    '０': '0', '１': '1', '２': '2', '３': '3', '４': '4', '５': '5', '６': '6', '７': '7', '８': '8', '９': '9'
};

inputField.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    // Might be enough to only check insertFromPaste inputType
    if (e.inputType !== 'insertCompositionText') {
        convertToHalfWidth(e);
    }
})

inputField.addEventListener('compositionend', convertToHalfWidth);

function convertToHalfWidth(e) {
    const input = e.target.value;
    // Replacing full-width numbers with their half-width counterparts
    const convertedInput = input.replace(/[０-９]/g, match => fullToHalfMap[match]);
    // Updating the input field with the converted value
    inputField.value = convertedInput;
}
<input type="text" id="inputField">




Thank you. I've also tried in this way. However, the user requires that I need to show the converted half-width character directly. I mean when the user will type any full-width character it'll print the respective half-width value inside that input field. The full-width character shouldn't be shown for a moment.

You're so close! I think the issue was that ０ was being converted to zero, but I'm not able to verify that. I also didn't see the 00 output you described (I'm using Firefox if that matters). However, I did observe that no replacement was made. This was solved by forcing the match output to a string with match.toString()


function convertToHalfWidth(input) {
    console.log(input);
    // Map of full-width to half-width numbers
    const fullToHalfMap = {
        '０': '0', '１': '1', '２': '2', '３': '3', '４': '4',
        '５': '5', '６': '6', '７': '7', '８': '8', '９': '9'
    };

    // Replacing full-width numbers with their half-width counterparts
    const convertedInput = input.replace(/[０-９]/g,
        match => fullToHalfMap[match.toString()]);

    // Updating the input field with the converted value
    document.getElementById('inputField').value = convertedInput;
}
<input type="text" id="inputField" oninput="convertToHalfWidth(this.value)">



